# something wrong about T.gt()

Tags: python, if-statement, theano

In order to obtain the usage of T.gt(), i wrote a toy code.

```
def f(data):
    # return T.gt(data, 0)
    if T.gt(data, 0):
        print "1"
        return -data
    else:
        print "2"
        return data


a = T.scalar()
t = f(a)

print t.eval({a:-4})
```

I expect the returned value is -4 when a=-4 and -4 when a=4, but it always satisfy the condition and run the return -data.
I don't know why. Can you help me?

Comment: Start by checking the values that `T.gt(data, 0)` return. Is it ever a falsy value? (None, False, 0, '', [], {}) ?

Comment: I have checked, it's return 0 if data=-4 or 1 if data=4. I wonder why it's not work for the above code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`T.gt` is a *symbolic* function; it doesn't return a Boolean value, instead it returns an object representing a symbolic expression that, when later compiled and executed, will evaluate to a Boolean value.

So, in Python, `T.gt(...)` will always be evaluated as `True` because the result is always non-`None`.

If you want a conditional expression in Theano then you need to use a symbolic conditional operation. There are two: `T.switch` and `theano.ifelse.ifelse`. The difference is that `T.switch` is an element-wise operation, accepting a tensor condition, while `ifelse` requires a scalar condition.

There is another problem with your example. Even if the code was good, it would always return a negative value. In essence your example says, *if input is positive return its negative else return the input as-is (which is already negative)*. I would also recommend using `theano.function` over the `eval` function.

Your example could be altered to illustrate the workings of `ifelse` like this:

```
import theano
import theano.ifelse
import theano.tensor as T


def symbolic_f(x):
    return theano.ifelse.ifelse(T.gt(x, 0), -x - 1, x + 1)


def main():
    x = T.scalar()
    f = theano.function(inputs=[x], outputs=symbolic_f(x))

    print f(-4)
    print f(4)


main()
```

Comment: How about comparing with two variables (not numpy) and return bool? I can not solve it. Could you help me?